# For each loop error in Parse image query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm writing a function to query the class Photos with a given Object Id in order to download a photo and set it to the UIImageView "background." I've narrowed the issue down to "for object in objects!" which I've commented in the code below. This seems like standard practice for casting, but the code won't run past this point. It compiles and no errors are thrown, but it fails to print anything past the "for" line, much less set the background.

```
// set new background image
func imageSet(objId: String) {
    var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Photos")
    query.whereKey("objId", equalTo:objId)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("First query")
            // last working line
                for object in objects! {
                    println("Won't print here")
                    // won't pass this point
                let userImageFile = object["image"] as! PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        println("Or here")
                        self.background.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    else {
            println("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `objects.count > 0`?

Comment: Yep! I put                 `if objects != nil{
                    println("not empty")
                }` right before the for loop and it printed. Putting it as the first line of the for loop doesn't print still, though.